# Getting a laravel script ready for clients

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm developing a paid application that is based on laravel.
 I want ideas about how to package the app and how to decrease laravel file size and get rid of all laravel components that is of no use on production/every case, for example: Boris , Predis and maybe Swift email .. 
What is the proper way to remove them and what other parts of laravel can be removed with no effects?

Scripts could be used in shared hosting or by people with minimum  and tech knowledge .. So, it should be easy for them

Comment: Just send everything without the `vendor` folder and run `composer install`?

Comment: Those extra stuffs are defined in vendor/laravel/framework/composer.json. I don't think you can easily modify laravel to not include them. However, you can probably easily delete their folders from vendor, if you're certain you're not gonna ever need them.

Comment: @Raphael_ The script could be used in shared hosting or by people with minimum and tech knowledge .. So, it should be easy for them

Comment: What's easier than typing two words and waiting? Maybe typing one only? Heck, make an alias then.

Comment: If the people can't run composer on the hosting, just wrap the whole thing and be done with it - yes, it's large, but if you zip it, it has just over 8 MB - no big deal.

Comment: @Raphael_ lol, never came across a paid script that asks for this.

Comment: @MightyPork Yeah I think so, although my code base is a bit large, it would be kinda like 20MB total... this sounds like the only solution there.

Comment: Also.. don't forget how laravel is meant to be installed. The "public" folder is what the people can visit with browser. All above it should live in a folder HIGHER, not accessible at all from outside world. Some people redirect root to /public with .htaccess, but that is BAD IDEA and not how it's meant to work. (just reminding.. in case you were tempted to do that.. it works, but it's ugly and less safe).

Comment: @MightyPork Oh yeah I forgot about this! Is it just less safe because passwords like DB password can be shown if there is a misconfiguration in PHP handler that enables .php files to get shown in clear text instead of parsing?

Comment: @Naughty.Coder Something like that, yes - you're potentially exposing your source and config files to public. I'm not exactly sure about the reasons, but it's officially discouraged.

Comment: if for shared hosting, there is no way to reduce much ! If on vps or dedicated you could update composer but while on shared hosting client needs the vender folder updated. (Y) good luck!